# hibernate - NullPointerException with getEntityManager..createNativeQuery()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception

after I call persist twice  then call `findLegacyLinks` App crashed with log below

```
 agentEao.persist(agent);
 ticketEao.persist(ticket);
```

agentEao instance of AgentEao

```
public class AgentEao extends JPAEao<Agent, Long>{
.... 


}
```

AgentEao extend JPAEao

```
public class JPAEao<E, PK extends Serializable>
        implements BaseEao<E, PK>, Serializable {
 
public E persist(E entity) {
        entity = (E) getSession().merge(entity); // getEntityManager().merge(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}


public List<String> findLegacyLinks(Long id) {
        Query query = getEntityManager()
                .createNativeQuery(
                        "SELECT entity_id FROM migration.mig_entity_merged_map WHERE merged_entity_id=?");
        //query.addScalar("merged_entity_id");
        query.setParameter(1, id);
        return query.getResultList();

    }
```

the error stack

```
 18:25:18,074 ERROR [com.berwick.security.DefaultExceptionHandler] (default task-176) Uncaught rest exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.type.LongType.next(LongType.java:79) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.LongType.next(LongType.java:40) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getNextVersion(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:399) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:296) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:160) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1335) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.beforeQuery(QueryImpl.java:484) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:447) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="com.berwick.dal" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/berwick</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.berwick.db.BerwickPostgresDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
```

any thought why this happens

Comment: Are you sure that you pass not null id into the `findLegacyLinks` method?

Comment: yea I am sure I was debugging and see the value passed correctly